# Can't register assembly in .Net GAC

Tags: .net, gac, gacutil

I'm facing a problem with registering assembly to GAC. I'm using Win8 x64. I need to register it in .Net GAC. It means that assembly should appear here c:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL. In gacutil console I get message "Assembly successfully added to the cache", but physically it doesn't appear. I tried to use gacutils from next locations:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64\
```

All these gacutils working with cache located at C:\Windows\assembly.

So my question is where located gacutil.exe to register assemblies into .Net GAC.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It appears that library was build in .net 2, and it can not appear here c:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL because it is GAC for assemblies build in .net 4 and higher. So I just take library build in .net 4 and register it using gacutil from

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64
```